# Over which rings is matrix rank defined?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, matrix-rank

I'm investigating $m \times n$ matrices over $R$, where $R$ is a finite commutative unitary ring, and more specifically a finite chain ring or a principal ideal ring. Define the row rank as the maximal number of lin. independent rows, the column rank in a similar manner, and the inner rank. My question is, are there necessary and sufficient conditions for $R$ such that the row rank is equal to the column rank, so that the term matrix rank is well-defined? I know that the two ranks coincide, for example, over a PID, and in this case they also coincide with other notions of rank I have encountered, such as the McCoy rank and the determinantal rank, but in general I don't know when I have the right to speak about the rank of a matrix. A reference would be welcome.

Comment: Your question isn't so much about "matrix ranks" as it is about the existence and uniqueness of a number of linearly independent elements in a free module, i.e. the rank of the submodule of $R^n$ ( or $R^m$) generated by those rows.  You should take a look at the first chapter of Lam's *Lectures on modules and rings* which discusses the invariant basis number and rank/strong rank conditions.